# What is the ASP.NET equivalent to PHP sessions?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, session

I am in the process of converting an old PHP application to ASP.NET.

I am not sure that equivalent of PHP sessions I should be using in ASP.NET.

In the existing application the login form checks credentials against a database and if the credentials are correct some data from the customer is returned from the database and set in the PHP session variables.

**For example:**

```
<?php

// credentials are correct

$_SESSION['customer_id']   = $result1;
$_SESSION['customer_name'] = $result2;

?>
```

These are then used elsewhere in the application to pull only data relating to that customer when querying the database etc.

**For example:**

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales_orders WHERE customer_id = ". $SESSION['customer_id'] ."";

?>
```

What is the ASP.NET equivalent to PHP sessions to do a similar sort of behaviour?

Comment: Traditional ASP.NET? It's `Session`.

Comment: I was curious so googling `asp.net session variables` yields lots of info.

Comment: Here's a page, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link. there are many was to store the state in asp.net. it looks like you are looking for Session state.

State info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Session state info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx